# Q: Can I insert integer/number in parameter code for Azure's JSON template code in Terraform?

Tags: json, azure, terraform, hcl

We want to deploy our infrastructure through Terraform on Azure cloud. The code I want to apply uses JSON template code made by Azure itself.

Code (scrubbed and removed unimportant JSON code):

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "docker" {
  name     = "CSI-DockerSwarm"
  location = "West Europe"
}

 resource "azurerm_template_deployment" "Docker" {
   name                = "Example-Deployment"
   resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.docker.name}"

    template_body = <<DEPLOY        # JSON beginning
    {
     "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
     "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
     "parameters": {
       "agentCount": {
         "allowedValues": [
           1,
           2,
           3,
           4,
         ],
         "defaultValue": 2,
         "metadata": {
            "description": "The number of agents for the cluster. This value can be from 1 to 100"
         },
         "type": "int"
        },

    DEPLOY      # JSON ending

      # these key-value pairs are passed into the ARM Template's `parameters` block
      parameters {
        "agentCount" = "3"          # Should be a integer/number?
        "agentEndpointDNSNamePrefix" = "-secret-"
        "agentSubnet" = "10.0.0.0/16"
        "agentVMSize" = "Standard_D2_v2"
        "firstConsecutiveStaticIP" = "172.16.0.5"
        "linuxAdminUsername" = "-secret-"
        "masterEndpointDNSNamePrefix" = "-secret-"
        "masterSubnet" = "172.16.0.0/24"
        "masterVMSize" = "Standard_D2_v2"
        "sshRSAPublicKey" = "-secret-"
        "targetEnvironment" = "AzurePublicCloud"
      }

      deployment_mode = "Incremental"
    }
```

**The problem**

*agentCount* parameter value doesn't work.

**The error**

```
Error: Error applying plan:

1 error(s) occurred:

* azurerm_template_deployment.Docker: 1 error(s) occurred:

* azurerm_template_deployment.Docker: Error creating deployment: resources.DeploymentsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=400 Code="InvalidTemplate" Message="Deployment template validation failed: 'The provided value for the template parameter 'agentCount' at line '1' and column '494' is not valid.'."
```

***Q: How can I make the "agentCount" JSON parameter an integer?***

Comment: well, from the arm template standpoint this is correct

Comment: Heredocs require you to remove all indentation relative to them so your `template_body` that follows the `<<DEPLOY` line needs to be unindented by 4 spaces.

Comment: @4c74356b41 - Can you explain this?
This `agentCount` parameter does not work like the other parameters do. I want to edit the `agentCount` parameter to the _n_ amount of agents/vm's I want to deploy. 

I understand that the Azure made template is perfect, but why can I not change the parameters which are in the Terraform part written in HCL?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR - I tried fixing it exactly like you said and also a couple of other combinations, but it did not work and I got the same error. Appreciate the help tho!

Comment: @U.Durk i have no idea about crappyform. I'm only telling you that ARM Template part is correct

Comment: @4c74356b41 Ok. Well, thanks for the info and thank you for your time! :)

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately terraform cannot pass integer parameters. We pass all parameters as strings, and then convert those to integer variables like that:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "stringToConvert": { 
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "4"
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "integerFromString": "[int(parameters('stringToConvert'))]"
    }
    "resources": [],
    "outputs": {
        "intResult": {
            "type": "int",
            "value": "[variables('integerFromString')]"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is still not possible in terraform v12.6

Comment: The code provided is ARM template and it is pure its functionality that we use here. How that is dependant on terraform version?

Comment: I meant terraform 12.6 still doesn't support passing integer values to arm templates, so your answer is still current as of tf 12.6.  I'm hoping terraform will add this functionality in some future release.

Comment: @DracoAter are you aware if there is already solution to pass integer values into arm template?

Comment: @fascynacja I have no idea.